# How to view instance information on gcloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I want check the instance information specially storage  whether its read only,Full or read/Write through gcloud shell

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better and more direct way, but here's one way to do it that'll work anywhere, GCE or not. gcloud can print you an access token using your instance's credentials like so:

```
$> gcloud auth print-access-token
ya29.GlxcBCtxyP3xW1JwKL62vh4h_8W0vqH9awoCXgcYkOguBP2DKc4JxgHpX6HHuaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

You can then query the scope of that access token directly with Google's OAuth API:

```
$> curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29.GlxcBCtxyP3xW1JwKL62vh4h_8W0vqH9awoCXgcYkOguBP2DKc4JxgHpX6HHuaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
{
  "issued_to": "something.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "audience": "something.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "user_id": "1234567890",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudkms https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
  "expires_in": 3578,
  "email": "some@email.com",
  "verified_email": true,
  "access_type": "offline"
}
```

So a full command to get a list of scopes might look like this (assuming you have HTTPie and jq installed):

```
$> http 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo' \
   access_token==`gcloud auth print-access-token` |
   jq '.["scope"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to be on the instance to get this information. If you run

```
gcloud compute instances describe MY_INSTANCE --zone ZONE \
  --format="yaml(serviceAccounts)"
```

It will show service account used by the vm and the set of scopes it has:

```
serviceAccounts:
- email: xxx@bla.gserviceaccount.com
  scopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
```

You can use `--format` flag to do a lot what `jq` tool gives you or set `--format=json` and pipe it to `jq` to extract relevant info.